# Batch loop through comma separated text

Tags: csv, batch-file

I define a list of lib files like this in DOS Batch:

```
set libs=MSVCRT.LIB Kernel32.lib User32.lib,^
         MSVCRT.LIB Kernel32.lib User32.lib d3d9.lib,^
         MSVCRT.LIB Kernel32.lib User32.lib d3d9.lib OpenGL32.lib
```

and I have to pass each one of these to a compiler, based on the executable to be created. For now, I just want to know how to loop and get each one of these libraries lists. This is what I have now:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%f in ("%LIBRARIIEXTERNE%") do (
    if not "%%f" == "" (
        echo "F:%%f"
    )
    if not "%%g" == "" (
        echo "G:%%g"
    )
)
endlocal
```

So, I only get the first element and the last two ones joined. Is it possible to get each part of the list (separated by comma), no matter the number, or must I use `%%f, %%g, %%h`, which implies that I must know how many to expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set libs="MSVCRT.LIB Kernel32.lib User32.lib",^
         "MSVCRT.LIB Kernel32.lib User32.lib d3d9.lib",^
         "MSVCRT.LIB Kernel32.lib User32.lib d3d9.lib OpenGL32.lib"

for %%l in (%libs%) do (
  echo %%~l
)
```

comma is a standard delimiter in plain `FOR` loop.One thing that differs `FOR` and `FOR /F` is that the `FOR` iterate trough each item in a list.But! Space is also a delimiter so you need to quote each item in the list.(and you can dequote it with `%%~l`)

Comment: The problem is that it must ignore the spaces and I can't send quoted libraries to the CL compiler

Comment: Great! This has done the job and saved me a lot of time. Learned how to dequote it, too. Thanks